# email body sending twice in my c# application

Tags: c#

I have written a simple console file in c# that reads from excel. The excel spreadsheet contains a list of email addresses and i am looping through this list and sending an email to each email in the lis.

When i run my app , the app send the an email to the first email address in the excel sheet but when it gets to the second email address it sends the body of the email twice, one being the first from the email first email. Could someone direct to what i'm doing wrong in my loop below:

```
    foreach (var email in File)
    {

            mailbody.AppendFormat("<p style='font-family: Arial, Sans-Serif;'> Hi</p>");
            mailbody.AppendFormat("<p style='font-family: Arial, Sans-Serif;'> Hey!</p>");
            Mailer.SendEmailMessage("someemail@gmail.com", email.email, "", "Test Header", "", mailbody);





    }
    Console.WriteLine("Finished Sending");


}
```

Comment: You are using a variable that is declared outside of the foreach loop and appending to that without ever resetting it... i would just move that variable into the foreach loop

Comment: If you don't want the body from the First time through the loop, you need to reset the mailbody variable.   Probably inside your loop, before doing anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new mail body with each address.

```
foreach (var email in File)
{
    var mailbody = string.Empty;

    ...
}
```